# command key in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uikeycommand

The iOS simulator shortcuts frequently use the command key. I notice that when running in the simulator, attempts in my program to catch command-z, command-y, etc. don't work. I assume the reason is that the system interprets them as simulator commands, not keypresses to be passed to my iOS app.

Is there a way to change that behavior?

Answer (score 2):

For your case when you use **command-z**, **command-y**, etc. first time in simulator you paste it to Simulator buffer. For paste to your app you need add **Shift key** for second time **command-z+shift**, **command-y+shift**

1. command-c (copy any string in mac)
2. command-v (paste to simulator buffer)
3. command-v-shift (paste to your app)

I'm not sure for possible changes this behavior. Try to find the same shortcuts in Settings (Xcode and Mac)

Comment: Cool trick. Thanks. (Voted). BTW, the word is "paste", with a final "e".

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer

Comment: I didn't quite follow that. For example, my app has a custom binding for command-x. I try command-x followed by shift-command-x, but my app still doesn't see anything.

Comment: I'm not shure that it works with custom shortcuts binding. If you use for copy/paste custom key, for copy/paste in simulator try to use default keys